# выбрать строку по значению столбца mysql

Tags: mysql

Имеется простейшей структуры БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом при попытке достать из данной БД строку с значением info_key = company_value с помощью следующего запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `info_key` = company_name
```

Получаю ошибку #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'company_name' в 'where clause'
Что не так с запросом? Разве я пытаюсь выбрать столбец?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `info_key` = 'company_name'
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало.